# Create multiple data frame in a for loop in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following code:

```py
ENTREGAS_G1=['19052022','27052022',
             '02062022','06062022','13062022','20062022','27062022',
             '05072022','11072022','20072022','26072022',
             '01082022']

for i in range(len(ENTREGAS_G1)):
    print('INFORMACION_'+ENTREGAS_G1[i])
    
    lista_date = folder_listas+'/SOLICITUD_INFORMACION_'+ENTREGAS_G1[i]
    
    esta = DBF(os.path.join(lista_date,'SOLICITUD_INFORMACION_'+ENTREGAS_G1[i]+'_ESTABLECIMIENTOS.DBF'))
    DF_ESTA=pd.DataFrame(iter(esta))
    prec = DBF(os.path.join(lista_date,'SOLICITUD_INFORMACION_'+ENTREGAS_G1[i]+'_PRECIOS.DBF'))
    DF_PREC=pd.DataFrame(iter(prec))
    prod = DBF(os.path.join(lista_date,'SOLICITUD_INFORMACION_'+ENTREGAS_G1[i]+'_PRODUCTOS.DBF'))
    DF_PROD=pd.DataFrame(iter(prod))
    
    MERGE1 = pd.merge(DF_PREC, DF_PROD, on=['CVE_PRODUC','CVE_MARCA'])
    MERGE2 = pd.merge(DF_ESTA, MERGE1, on='FOLIO')
    
    globals()[PROFECO_+i] = MERGE2.assign(identrega=ENTREGAS_G1[i])
    
    print('Done:','PROFECO_'+ENTREGAS_G1[i])
```

My object is creating multiple data-frames like for example:

```
PROFECO_19052022
PROFECO_27052022
PROFECO_02062022
PROFECO_06062022
...
```

But my code does not work.

Any suggestions for improving my code?

Regards,
Alexis Rodas

Comment: Why can't you use a dictionary? You'll have a single holder for all your DFs, you can call them with nice names like `profeco[19052022]`, you can iterate over them easily...

Comment: "But my code does not work." What does it does instead? Raises an error (post the error message)? Produces a different output (explain what it does)? We don't have (and don't want) your data, so we need to know what happens in order to improve it.